# configure CORS setting in asp.net development server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, cors

I tried to configure CORS setting in web.config file. However, when i run my service, i can't seem to get CORS response header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"). So, does asp.net development server 9.0 allow to set CORS settings?

```
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
        <add name="HttpPostLocalhost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>

 </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your web.config
Adjust if needed. This example I only open for .aspx

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
      </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```